# WP_query call triggers a fatal error

Tags: php, wordpress

The fourth line below is creating an "Apache HTTP Server Stopped Working" error in my app. Anyone see anything that stands out?

```
$cat=get_cat_ID('top-menu');
$catHidden=get_cat_ID('hidden');
$myqueryCurrent = new WP_Query();
$myqueryCurrent->query(array('cat' => "$cat,-$catHidden",'post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts')));
```

This is running under WordPress 2.9.2
The same code in 3.0 runs fine. PHP is version 5.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Scott,

Again, we need to go deeper.  It would be helpful to have the actual mysql query that is being generated by the WP_Query object.

Can you put more debugging output into the WP_Query class, in the ->query method.

Furthermore, can you verify that get_option('sticky_posts') returns a comma separated list?

Comment: var_dump(get_option('sticky_posts')); returns array(1) { [0]=> int(9)}

Answer (score 0):

To ease out the debugging - enable debugging mode in wp-config.php in your WordPress root folder - i know i had problems with apache doing silly stuff if i had any error.

When enabled, please verify (as mentioned above) that everything you try to use in your query actually returns stuff

Comment: I can echo all of the items. When I print and exit just before the myqueryCurrent, the code executes fine up until that point. However, when I place the print/exit statement just below the query, I get the apache error.

Comment: have you enabled debugging? It might magically show some error. If you are fortunate enough, go check out the log files for apache - they always show why you get the errors :-)

Comment: I've been running this site all along with WP_Debug true. The problem is that this apparently is crashing at PHP.ini and never gets to the WP debug manager.